# NotImplementedError: Board not supported

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi/script) to read analog input.

But instead of using Raspberry Pi, I am trying to use a Jetson Nano to read MCP3008 channel 0 analog input only.

I am following the pin layout in the tutorial on Jetson Nano since it shares same layout with Raspberry Pi.

```
import busio
import digitalio
import board
import adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008 as MCP
from adafruit_mcp3xxx.analog_in import AnalogIn

# create the spi bus
spi = busio.SPI(clock=board.SCK, MISO=board.MISO, MOSI=board.MOSI)

# create the cs (chip select)
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D22)

# create the mcp object
mcp = MCP.MCP3008(spi, cs)

# create an analog input channel on pin 0
chan0 = AnalogIn(mcp, MCP.P0)

print('Raw ADC Value: ', chan0.value)
print('ADC Voltage: ' + str(chan0.voltage) + 'V')
```

The code above throws the error:

> ```
>     import board
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/board.py", line 98, in <module>
>     raise NotImplementedError("Board not supported")
> NotImplementedError: Board not supported
> ```

I checked the source code, it points to [this line](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Blinka/blob/a7bcbc4bc896176070770e9d7834402b4afa3020/src/board.py#L98).

However, I looked up of the **board** library source, it does support Jetson Nano because of the line

```
board_id == ap_board.JETSON_NANO
```

Any guide can help me further locate the issue will be very helpful. Thanks!